# MySQL: How to ORDER BY on multiple columns?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the the following columns on a table

```
type | date_1 | date_2 | date_3
```

type column is

```
ENUM('1','2','3')
```

I need to order by on date columns but use appropriate columns based on `type` column on every row.

Comment: Sample data and desired output would be nice

Comment: Also include anything you may have attempted. The first thing I would suggest based on only what you have so far, just google `ORDER BY clause`.

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: give some sample data in some part from your table

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the person has shown no attempt to solve the problem himself.

Comment: wait @Dan Bracuk maybe he has low connections and other bad connectivity issue. wait for his response for some hours.

Comment: if type column is 1 use date_1 column if type is 2 use date_2 column if type is 3 use date_3 column for ordering

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like

```
SELECT * 
FROM your_table 
ORDER BY IF(type='1', date_1, IF(type='2', date_2, date_3))
```

Comment: It worked i didnt know its possible to use different columns on every row for ordering

Comment: I must admit that the `CASE` example by jarlh below looks a little bit nicer. But nevertheless: what you're really doing is creating a *virtual* column using the given function/statement (`IF` or `CASE`) - this is just a column in the result set and that's the one that's being used for sorting. Please note that no indexes can be used for sorting here!

Comment: you answered first to my guestion thats why i  choosed your answer the best answer

Answer (score 2):

Use a `case` expression in the `order by` to get the correct value:

```
select *
from tablename
order by case type when 1 then date_1
                   when 2 then date_2
                   when 3 then date_3
         end
```